# What is font data table in assembly x86

Tags: assembly

For some months I've been learning some tutorials on making an OS, and I've done making my OS that is really simple, it's just displaying text and when menu is clicked, the menu will show up and displaying some program. But it's all done by me in mode 03h. But now, I want to modify it to mode 13h. But I don't know how to use text with normal font. I've been searching in google for a tutorial about how to use a normal font then I got an example that showing something called 'font table'. I already seen the font table, but I don't know how to use it with my 16-bit OS with mode 13h. Can anybody shows me please about what are they and how to use them? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Fonts are not related in any way to x86 assembly. What are you talking about mode 03h and mode 13h ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have outputted to the screen in video mode 03h with the BIOS functions then you can continue to use these in video mode 13h. The characters will still appear the same albeit larger.